# How to upgrade patch commmand?

Tags: ubuntu, patch

How do I upgrade the patch utility?

I am facing problems when I apply patch as follows.

```
patch -p6 < ../kernelpatchXXXX
```

New directories and files are getting created instead of modifying the existing files.

The patch version I use is as follows.

```
:~$ patch -v  
patch 2.6  
Copyright (C) 1988 Larry Wall  
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  

This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  
You may redistribute copies of this program  
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.  

written by Larry Wall and Paul Eggert
```

I checked the [Patch's GNU site](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/) and found there is a stable release version 2.7

Can someone help me upgrade?

Comment: Thinks like that usually arn't updated that often for a reason - might help to try to work out why the current version isn't working - what command are you using specfically, and with what files/patches?

Comment: I am trying to patch files which are related to a project's workspace. The same patches are being applied correctly in other location where the patch version is 2.5.9

Comment: wrong -p option?

Comment: Are you applying it in the same directory?

Comment: There is some difference in patch 2.5.9 and 2.6. I used WindRiver's patch utility and it worked correctly.